# Area enclosed by parametric curve

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $c(t)=(\cos^3t,\sin^3t)$. We want to find the area enclosed by this curve.

$$\begin{align}
\ A & = 4\int_{0} ^{1} {ydx} \\
    & = 4\int_{0} ^{\pi/2} {(\sin^3t)(-3\sin t \cos^2t) dt} \\
    & = ... \\
    & = -\frac{3 \pi}{8} \\
\end{align}$$

So I'm guessing the correct answer should be $\frac{3 \pi}{8}$.

Why is the resulting area negative? Are the limits wrong?

Comment: $\int y(t) d(x(t)) = - \int x(t) d(y(t))$

Comment: @DougM But doesn't it take a ccw trip here? And the result it negative

Comment: $x = 0$ and $1$ corresponds to $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$ respectively. So $\int_0^1 y dx = \int_{\pi/2}^0 \sin^3 t (-3\sin t\cos^2 t) dt = \int_0^{\pi/2}  \sin^3 t(3\sin t\cos^2 t)dt$.

Comment: @achillehui I thought this was wrong in some cases I've tried but nevermind it is correct. Many thanks.

Comment: @DougM On the equation you wrote, do the limits remain at the same positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first and second integrals aren't exactly equal to each other — they are negatives of each other, and that's why your answer came out negative:
$$\int_{0}^{1}y\,dx\neq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin^3t)(-3\sin t\cos^2t)\,dt$$
because in fact
$$\int_{0}^{1}y\,dx=-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin^3t)(-3\sin t\cos^2t)\,dt.$$
The reason is that when $t$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi/2$, the first-quarter portion of the graph is traced **from right to left**, i.e. in the negative direction, so $dx=(-3\sin t\cos^2t)\,dt$ is negative there. That's why you end up finding the value whose absolute value is equal to the area, but whose sign is negative — which reflects the direction of the curve.

Answer (score 1):

Parametric curves are just screaming out to be solved in the complex plane. Consider that

$$
z=\cos^3(t)+i\sin^3(t)\\
A=\frac{1}{2}\int\mathfrak{Im}\{z^* \dot z\}\ dt
$$
$$
z^*=\cos^3(t)-i\sin^3(t)\\
\dot z=3[-\cos^2(t)\sin(t)+i\sin^2(t)\cos(t)]\\
\mathfrak{Im}\{z^* \dot z\}=3\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)
$$

Therefore (corrected from an earlier version that only considered the $1^{st}$ quadrant)

$$A=\frac{4}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}3\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)dt=\frac{12}{2}\frac{1}{32}[4x-\sin(4x)]\big|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{3\pi}{8}$$

This result has been verified numerically.

Comment: Your answer is wrong for the closed curve. You have calculated only the part for the first quadrant ($0\to\pi/2$, not $0\to2\pi$). Anyway, the calculation is worth to see. Where this, $A=\frac{1}{2}\int\mathfrak{Im}\{z^* \dot z\}\ dt$, does come from?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, I see that I was missing the factor of 4 in the OP and have corrected the post. I do most everything with plane curves in the complex plane. My key reference is Zwikker, C. (1968). *The Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications*, Dover Press.